# How to make a wrapper to call functions in different classes?

Tags: php, ajax, wrapper

I'm trying to solve a problem in ajax which is coming out from the moment that my client asked me to not use any framework for web applications.
I have always used CodeIgniter and I never had any problem with ajax requests, especially when I had to call a method simply perform this call:

```
var postUrl = GlobalVariables.baseUrl + 'application/controllers/user.php/ajax_check_login';
//http://localhost/App_Name/application/controllers/user.php/ajax_check_login <-postUrl content

var postData =
{
    'username': $('#username').val(),
    'password': $('#password').val()
};

$.post(postUrl, postData, function(response)
{
        // do stuff...
});
```

How you can see from the code above what I want to do is call a method within the controller `user.php` whose name is `ajax_check_login`.
What I have done so far to achieve the desired result is to make this code:

```
$allowed_functions = array('ajax_check_login');
$ru  = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
$func = preg_replace('/.*\//', '', $ru);
if (isset($func) && in_array($func, $allowed_functions)) {
$user = new User();
$user->$func();
}
```

if you want to see the complete structure of a class [click here](http://pastebin.com/Ekk7TpME).
The problem is that this code should be placed inside each controller,
and you have to set all the methods offered, sometimes the function available reaching fifty, leads to discard this solution...
What I want to know is: how can I make a wrapper, a class that allows me to invoke a method of the controller from url and execute it?

Before all this work was done by CodeIgniter. So now I have to write my own class that allows me to access the controls easily and recall methods in different classes.
All classes that have to respond to ajax request reside in application/controllers / ... folder. In the controllers folder I have 20 controllers.

Comment: do you have to pass username, password (or whatever posted) to the function, or the functions all take it from $_POST?

Comment: all function take the content to elaborate from the postData variable that is different in each ajax request

Comment: What makes your client sure you'd need to reinvent the wheel in the first place? More, precise, frameworks are there for a good reason - *not* to come up with arbitrary solutions like you're just doing. That being said, you might as well take a look at [slim](http://slimframework.com)

Comment: I tried to make him understand this, but he's a purist code and does not allow external dependencies. However, the class of routers is all you need, as it will be easier then convert the code into the CI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add ajax.php:

```
<?php
preg_match_all('/([^\/.]*)\.php\/([^\/]*)$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);
$class = $matches[1][0];
$func = $matches[2][0];

$allowed_classes = array('user','account','foo');
if (isset($class) && isset($func) && in_array($class, $allowed_classes)) {
  require_once "application/controllers/" . $class. ".php";
  // here you could do some security checks about the requested function
  // if not, then all the public functions will be possible to call
  // for example if you don't want to allow any function to be called
  // you can add a static function to each class:
  // static function getAllowedFunctions() {return array('func1','func2');}
  // and use it the same way you had checked it in the question
  $obj = new $class();
  $obj->$func();
  // or if need to pass $_POST:
  // call_user_func(array($obj, $func, $_POST));
}
```

and in javascript post to:

```
var postUrl = GlobalVariables.baseUrl + 'application/controllers/ajax.php/user.php/ajax_check_login';
```

If you have apache, then you might be able to do it even without adding ajax.php by adding this to .htaccess in the controller directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /baseUrl.../application/controllers/
RewriteRule ^([^\.]*\.php)/[^/]*$ ajax.php?file=$1&func=$2
```

Of course you need your real baseUrl there. And change the 1st 3 lines in the php to:

```
$class = $_GET['class'];
$func = $_GET['func'];
```

Comment: Well I guess the first solution is better 'cause I must know the url, in any case I doesn't know the url. @Gavriel when I perform the ajax request this error appear in the network tab: 500 (Internal server error)

Comment: checking the server error log I found the cause: require_once(application/controllers/user.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>A:\Utenti\John\Programmi\Bitnami\Wampstack\apache2\htdocs\myapp\application\controllers\ajax.php

seems that the code inserted also ajax.php at the end of url

Comment: I fix the problem putting:  `require_once dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . "\\application\\controllers\\" . $class. ".php";`

Comment: Try just `require_once $class. ".php";`

Comment: which type of security controls I should execute in the ajax router?

Comment: If you want to enable to call every public function, then it's ok, but if there might be functions which you don't want to expose, then you'll need to filter

Comment: filter? What do you mean?

Comment: in the example I have `$allowed_classes`, and only allow those classes/files. If you'd request "bar" I would refuse to execute it even if it exists. You could do the same for $func if you want, but less important, just make only those functions public that you want to allow